# jenkins install errorno -3 error performing checksum on RHEL 5.7

Tags: sqlite, jenkins, yum

I tried to install Jenkins on an RHEL 5.7 server (sudo yum install Jenkins) and I keep getting the error shown below:

> http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/repodata/a4a18ee2ec13db4b127e320edc4c7b7c9fbf1139a4505278b2c03727d3ca606b-primary.sqlite.bz2:
>   [Errno -3] Error performing checksum Trying other mirror. Error:
>   failure:
>   repodata/a4a18ee2ec13db4b127e320edc4c7b7c9fbf1139a4505278b2c03727d3ca606b-primary.sqlite.bz2
>   from jenkins: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

I tried

- Adding “http_cache=packages” to the yum.conf file
- Ran “createrepo –s sha /etc/yum.repos.d”
- Ran “sudo yum clean all”

But I still get the error. Any clues as to why this error is occurring?

Thanks,
Ralph.

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like there is allready a ticket regarding this problem:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/INFRA-685

In order to upgrade jenkins I download the latest rpm from:

http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/

and instaled manualy with 
rpm -Uvh jenkins-2.10-1.1.noarch.rpm
This will only upgrade jenkins but on my system, also a CentOS 5.11, yum update still have problems with perfoming checksum for jenkins packages. For me is at the moment acceptable.

Cheers, duderoot.